# Angular WebApi Post call by Passing a single Parameter

Tags: angular-http, webapi

**Web Api Controller Method**

```
        [Route("change-gross-profit")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult UpdateGrossProfit(decimal grossProfit)
        {          
            var customerGrossProfit = grossProfit / 100;
            Context.UpdateCustomerCost();
            return Ok();            
        }
```

**Angular Http Call**

```
public updateGrossProfit(grossProfit: number): Observable<void> {
        const url = UrlTemplate.populate('api/customer/total', 'change-gross-profit', {});
        return this._http.post<void>(url, grossProfit ,{withCredentials: true});                   
    }
```

I am getting the *404 Method Not Found error*.

I have also tried by passing data using **JSON.stringify({'grossProfit' : grossProfit})** *(Getting un-supported content-type error.)*

Currently workaround is, I can create a class with required property and then pass that class instance as a body which I know that it will work. But I would like to avoid it as there is only one parameter that I want to pass into POST controller method so.

Any idea how can I pass the single parameter as an argument to Post controller method from Angular without creating a custom object?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the number just fine.
I tried the same with this code below and it works fine.

```
let no : number =5;
this.http.post<any>("https://xxxxx/postDecimal", no).subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
    });
```

This is my backend code:

```
 [HttpPost("postDecimal")]
 [ProducesResponseType(typeof(int), 200)]
 [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), 400)]
 [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), 403)]
 public async Task<IActionResult> PostDecimal(decimal x)
 {
      return Ok(x);
 }
```

Is your url fine? Since you got 404 Method not found error.